# Laravel: How to make pagination correctly?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I'll return messages current user from database in three arrays: $today, $year and $pastYear messages with query:

```
$today_messages = Inbox::where($message, $user_id)
                                 ->whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())
                                 ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
                                 ->get();

$year_messages = Inbox::where($message, $user_id)
                                ->whereBetween('created_at', [now()->startOfYear(), Carbon::yesterday()->endOfDay()])
                                ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
                                ->get();

$past_year_messages = Inbox::where($message, $user_id)
                                     ->where('created_at', '<', now()->startOfYear())
                                     ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
                                     ->get();
$messages = [
                       'today' => $today_messages,
                       'year'  => $year_messages,
                       'pastYear' => $past_year_messages
                    ];
```

And I will return three array and print this arrays in view using three loop `foreach()`. Simple code display messages which sended today to current user:

```
@if(count($today) > 0)
    @foreach($today as $message)
    <tr @if($message->seen == 0) class="unread"
        @elseif($message->seen == 1) class=""
        @endif
        >
        <td class="inbox-small-cells">
            <div class="checkbox checkbox-default inline-block">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox012"/>
                <label for="checkbox012"></label>
            </div>
            <i class="zmdi zmdi-star inline-block font-16"></i>
        </td>
        <td class="view-message  dont-show"><a href="{{ route('sended'). '/' .encrypt($message->id) }}">{{$message->subject}}</a>@if($message->seen == 0)<span class="label label-warning pull-right">new</span>@endif</td>
        <td class="view-message ">{{$message->messageSender->name}}</td>
        <td class="view-message  text-right">
            <i class="zmdi zmdi-attachment inline-block mr-15 font-16"></i>
            <span  class="time-chat-history inline-block">{{ $message->created_at->format('H:m') }}</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

And how I can create correct pagination for current user messages?

Comment: Do you need a pagination for each group?

Comment: Not. A must create one pagination for all group messages.

Comment: Laravel has a pretty nice documentation on pagination: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination

Comment: You have 3 different groups of data. Why should you use a single pagination? You are showing us a single block of data (today) of the table. If your need is just show a "header" before each group of message, think to make a single (and faster) query, paginate it and make your "time check" while looping along all the messages.

Comment: What if these collections will have 5 (today), 10 (this year) and 20 (last years) pages and a user will click page number 20. You'll show the last page of the "last year messages" and what do you want to show for "today messages" and for "this year messages"?

Comment: I do not know answer the question. But as if in my need to output 10 messages on each page. But how to do this by combining three message arrays, I just did not think of it. @Alexey Mezenin

Comment: @MaxNet is `$today` having data?

Comment: @Abdulla Nilam $today - maybe it can and does not have a message in the array

Comment: whats your issue??  explain please

Comment: The problem is that how to combine 3 arrays to create a single pagination in which on each page there will be 10 messages. @Abdulla Nilam

Comment: did you tried merging the arrays before pass to view??

Comment: Yes, but to merge an array seems to be no problem. But if I will merge the array then I can not output the date in the correct format for each message type. For example, I will output the date for today's messages in the format ('H:m'), for messages that are received in this year in the format ('M d') and for messages that were received in the previous year in the format ('Y-m-d'). @Abdulla Nilam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$perPage = 10;
$today = Inbox::where($message, $user_id)->whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())->latest()->paginate($perPage);
$thisYear = Inbox::where($message, $user_id)->whereBetween('created_at', [now()->startOfYear(), Carbon::yesterday()->endOfDay()])->latest()->paginate($perPage);
$pastYear = Inbox::where($message, $user_id)->where('created_at', '<', now()->startOfYear())->latest()->paginate($perPage);
$maxPages = max($today->lastPage(), $year->lastPage(), $pastYear->lastPage());
```

Pass these three variables and `$maxPages` to the view. Then create pagination links manually:

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < $maxPages $i++)
    <a href="{{ route('some.route') }}?page={{ $i }}">{{ $i }}</a>
    {{ $loop->last ? '' : ' - ' }}
@endfor
```

If you don't want to create these links manually, you could try to use `LenghAwarePaginator` with an empty collection or something. But since you have three collections, I'd manually create these links to keep it simple and maintainable.

Comment: I can't return $maxPages to view. If I add it to returned array and dump in view given error `Undefined variable: maxPages`. But if I dump it in [controller](http://mahorat.org/Controller.zip) given number 1

Comment: @MaxNet `return view('your.view', compact('today', 'thisYear', 'pastYear', 'maxPages'));`

Comment: Instead of a variable $loop what I must write?

Comment: @MaxNet use exactly this variable. You can read about Laravel's [the loop variable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#the-loop-variable)

Comment: `Undefined variable: loop` given if I use var $loop

Comment: @MaxNet if you're using 5.5 it should work. You can also do it manually `{{ $i === $maxPages - 1 ? : '' : ' - ' }}`

Comment: @MaxNet sure you can, but the thing is you have three paginator objects, so some you need to do additional stuff for some things.

Comment: Meaning to use pagination methods will not be logical in my situation.

Comment: My navigation type so: `1-10 of 100  <   >`

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what do you mean.

Comment: @MaxNet well, you determine what paginator has the most items in it and display this number instead of `100`. And to count `1-10`, use the `currentPage()` and `perPage()` on the paginator instance with the most items in it.

Comment: I must call method `currentPage()` using var $today->currentPage()? Generally. Works with three objects of pagination as it is not clear. Identify the current page or the previous page. Thank you for the answer @Alexey

Comment: @MaxNet as I said you need to determine what paginator has the most items. Then use it to get the current page, previous page etc. You can also get current page with `request('page', 1)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162977/discussion-between-max-net-and-alexey-mezenin).

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel built in paginate method on query like this.

```
$today_messages = Inbox::where($message, $user_id)
                             ->whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())
                             ->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(10)
```

It will automatically create pagination after 10 records
you can choose any limit for pagination and if you need to add results to Your view then you can use custom code to add many options to your view
like this

```
<?php echo $today_messages->render(); ?>
<?php echo $today_messages->total(); ?>
```

You can use many other options to your views

Answer (score 0):

I have used `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator` in my project to create pagination in my laravel project and then consumed it as :

```
function paginate($items, $perPage)
{
    if(is_array($items)){
        $items = collect($items);
    }

    return new Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator(
        $items->forPage(Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() , $perPage),
        $items->count(), $perPage,
        Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::resolveCurrentPage(),
        ['path' => Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::resolveCurrentPath()]
    );
}
```

you can read more about this API at : https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Pagination/Paginator.html (assuming you are using laravel 5.5)

i hope this helps. happy coding!